# Jenkins - How do I send an email on the FxCop reports with warnings and issues

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fxcop

I am investigating on a way to send an email with graphical representation of FxCop warnings/Issues right after a build is performed on any end states. Is there any plugin or way that I can achieve this ?. Currently after the build the FxCop runs and displays the results in the Jenkins dashboard.

Comment: By the way, this question is broad and opinion based. Narrow down your question with your findings,

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, you can configure Jenkins with SES which is provided by AWS. By creating an SMTP server in SES service.

[Here is the documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html)